# consolidating rulesets with LESS

Tags: css, less

Why is LESS outputting two rulesets each for `ol.start > li` and `ol.start > li:before`? How can I minimize/consolidate the amount of rulesets that LESS compiles?

**LESS:**

```
.myMixin(){
     list-style-type: none !important;
     > li {
          padding: .5em 0em;
          &:before {
               list-style-position: outside;
          }
     }
}
ol.start {
          .myMixin();
        //  list-style-type: none !important;
          counter-reset: sAd 0;
          > li {
               //padding: .5em 0em;
               counter-increment: sAd;
               &:before {
                    content: counter(sAd, upper-alpha) ". ";
               }
     }
}
```

**compiled CSS:**

```
ol.start {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  counter-reset: sAd 0;
}
ol.start > li {
  padding: .5em 0em;
}
ol.start > li:before {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ol.start > li {
  counter-increment: sAd;
}
ol.start > li:before {
  content: counter(sAd, upper-alpha) ". ";
}
```

Comment: In short: automatic selector merging is actually quite complicated task than it may look like, see [#1468](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1468) and issues referenced from there.

Comment: Because your mixin contains the same selectors with different code

Comment: It is so tiny things, it will be better to use some compress library like Uglify or YUI Compressor and forget about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments above explain why Less isn't merging those by default, so to answer the second part of the question:

> How can I minimize/consolidate?

You could use the following Less options: `--clean-css --clean-option=--advanced`, but unfortunately this option seems to have no effect in current (1.7.4) Less version due to some bug (internal Less `--clean-css` options seem to be out of sync with `clean-css` version included). So I'd recommend to use [`clean-css`](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) directly (the tool itself or a corresponding plugin for an "automated build environment" such as `grunt` or `gulp` if you use any).

(Actually personally I always use separate `clean-css` build step instead of `less` built-in option because it's much easier to control and update).

**-**

`advanced` (which is `off` by default in `lessc`, but `on` by default in `clean-css` itself) enables merging of identical selectors (plus some other "advanced" optimizations - see corresponding docs for more details).

---

### Update:

Actually I've misinformed you above, sorry. In fact there's no bug in Less with `--clean-option=--advanced` option. It works as it should but in newer `clean-css` versions (incl. those installed with Less 1.7.x) they just disabled merging of identical selectors *if* there's any other selector in between (and I was comparing to an earlier `clean-css` version where this worked before they changed things in [**v2.1.8**](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/blob/master/History.md#218--2014-03-28)). So for the moment it looks like `clean-css` tool also won't merge the selectors in the original snippet - unless I'm missing some of its options (Probably some other CSS-minifier tool with more aggressive "unsafe" merging options would help).

---

So to summarize all above:
`--clean-css --clean-option=--advanced` Less option will merge selectors in:

```
foo {bar: baz}
foo {baz: bar}
```

But **won't** in:

```
foo {bar: baz}
baz {bar: foo}
foo {baz: bar}
```